# CSS Not showing when pushed to website but shows in development mode on my mac in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

This is my website, it is not showing any of the styling but on my localhost it shows styling... any ideas?
https://jaydenszekely.com/

All looks good to me but I must have missed something.

All my code is here :) https://github.com/deslabcreative/jaydenszekely

Nothing out of the ordinary in log that I notice :)

Please Help!

Comment: Do you have a separate style sheet or is it all inline styling?

Comment: where is your style file ?

Comment: Where you import your css file?

Comment: I Import my style in the Layout.JS File –  It's all.sass

Answer (score 1):

On gitHub, in your index.html, you have opening and closing style tags in your head section.  This seems to be missing from the copy on your public website from looking at the source and inspecting it FireFox inspector.

Copy the opening and closing style tags and everything in between them, paste it into your head section just before the closing head tag, and it should work

Edit: It looks like you are using gatsby to generate your site.  Have you seen this -> https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/4816

Comment: Thanks, I import my SASS from all.sass in my Layout.JS File...  Any ideas?  Ive done it like this before and was working until 2 pushes ago and unsure what would have made this change

Comment: Also still works on my local host server while developing

Comment: I have also just pushed the old version back up to the website but current code is still in GitHub :)